# Ubuntu 23.11 + TPM Full Disk Encryption + Esxi/VMWare

Tags: ubuntu, disk-encryption, tpm

Has anyone gotten TPM + FDE working on a VM in ESXi?

I got through the installation but after reboot the system would not start, a screen comes up with /EndEntire and then the following errors:

[image]

When booting from the LiveCD, I get responses from the TPM module.. such as sudo tpm2_pcrread, sudo tpm2_getcap

Comment: Do you have a way to [retrieve the UUID's](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-retrieve-and-change-partitions-universally-unique-identifier-uuid-on-linux) from a RescueCD etc. for the newly created system.  Either the UUID written in `fstab` is the one from the install or was created by the install and not written properly.  Once we get the disk mounted we can investigate the encryption etc.